# Transform XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform the XML using XSLT
Here is my sample XML

```
<EmployeList>
  <EMpDetails>
    <Name>Kiran</Name>
    <ID>ID001</ID>
    <city>Hyderabad</city>
    <Country>India</Country>
  </EMpDetails>
  <EMpDetails>
    <Name>Sunny</Name>
    <ID>ID002</ID>
    <city>Banglore</city>
    <Country>INDIA</Country>
  </EMpDetails>
  <EMpDetails>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <ID>ID001</ID>
    <city>TEXAS</city>
    <Country>US</Country>
  </EMpDetails>
  <EMpDetails>
    <Name>Raj</Name>
    <ID>ID006</ID>
    <city>Dallas</city>
    <Country>US</Country>
  </EMpDetails>
  <EMpDetails>
    <Name>Nag</Name>
    <ID>ID007</ID>
    <city>ITALY</city>
    <Country>Rome</Country>
  </EMpDetails>
</EmployeList>
```

Required output using XSLT

```
<EmployeList>
  <EMpDetails>
    <Name>Kiran</Name>
    <ID>ID001</ID>
    <city>Hyderabad</city>
    <Country>India</Country>
  </EMpDetails>
  <EMpDetails>
    <Name>Sunny</Name>
    <ID>ID002</ID>
    <city>Banglore</city>
    <Country>INDIA</Country>
  </EMpDetails>   
</EmployeList>
```

Comment: Could you specify your Xml with tags?

Comment: And what is the rule? Like, remove everything that is not `<Country>India</Country>`?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two complete solutions (for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0) that are based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the overriding of the identity rule/template. Explanation is also provided.

Comment: Should be City=Rome and Country=ITALY and not the other way around :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work as you need (assuming that you want all `EMpDetails` elements where `Country` is equal to `India` with case-insensitivity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="EmployeList">
        <EmployeList>
            <xsl:copy-of select="EMpDetails[lower-case(Country) = 'india']"/>
        </EmployeList>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is a small problem in your solution -- a wrong and misleading `version` attribute that would lead people to believe they can use this with an XSLT 1.0 processor. Please, correct.

Comment: Thanks to @empo for editing the answer and correcting the version. I am still not deleting my comment so that the original author confirms he has seen it and will know not to make such mistakes in the future.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, @empo: Thanks for correcting. lower-case() function is available in XPath 2.0 (strange that Oxygen XML didn't complain about that..). For 1.0 version translate() function made the job.

Comment: HI Thanks for the reply and solution can you provide me the any docs on XML to XML transformation using XSLT

Comment: @kiran425: At beginning you can start with W3schools XML Tutorials (http://www.w3schools.com/): (Learn XML), Learn XPath, Learn XSLT (in practice you can't write XSLT without knowing XPath). There aren't fully comprehensive, but easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the question asks to output only `EMpDetails` whose `Country` child has a string (case-insensitive) value of `"India"`:

**I. This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "EMpDetails
    [not(translate(Country,
                   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                   )
         ='india'
         )
    ]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<EmployeList>
    <EMpDetails>
        <Name>Kiran</Name>
        <ID>ID001</ID>
        <city>Hyderabad</city>
        <Country>India</Country>
    </EMpDetails>
    <EMpDetails>
        <Name>Sunny</Name>
        <ID>ID002</ID>
        <city>Banglore</city>
        <Country>INDIA</Country>
    </EMpDetails>
    <EMpDetails>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <ID>ID001</ID>
        <city>TEXAS</city>
        <Country>US</Country>
    </EMpDetails>
    <EMpDetails>
        <Name>Raj</Name>
        <ID>ID006</ID>
        <city>Dallas</city>
        <Country>US</Country>
    </EMpDetails>
    <EMpDetails>
        <Name>Nag</Name>
        <ID>ID007</ID>
        <city>ITALY</city>
        <Country>Rome</Country>
    </EMpDetails>
</EmployeList>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<EmployeList>
   <EMpDetails>
      <Name>Kiran</Name>
      <ID>ID001</ID>
      <city>Hyderabad</city>
      <Country>India</Country>
   </EMpDetails>
   <EMpDetails>
      <Name>Sunny</Name>
      <ID>ID002</ID>
      <city>Banglore</city>
      <Country>INDIA</Country>
   </EMpDetails>
</EmployeList>
```

**II. This XSLT 2.0 transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "EMpDetails[not(upper-case(Country)='INDIA')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**again produces the same, wanted and correct result**.

**Explanation**: Overriding the identity rule with a template matching all unwanted `EMpDetails` elements. This template has empty body, which effectively prevents copying any such matched elements to the output.

**Remember**: Using and overriding the identity rule/template is the most fundamental and most powerful XSLT design pattern.

Comment: If `'india'` is fixed, `not(translate(Country, 'INDA', 'inda') = 'india')` would probably be more efficient.

Comment: HI Thanks for the reply and solution. can you provide me any docs to get more XSLT

Comment: @kiran425: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample input is simple as it's shown you could also go with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/EmployeList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="EMpDetails[
                Country[
                .='India'
                or .='INDIA']
                ]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply and solution can send me any link or documents to study more on XSLT